# Find the solutions of equations of the form $ax^2+by^2 = z^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

How can I find the non-trivial solutions $(x, y, z)$ (if there are any)  of the equation

> $95 x^2 + 111 y^2 = z^2$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ ?

Is there any method I can use ?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1513733/solving-a-diophantine-equation-of-the-form-x2-ay2-byz-cz2-with-the-co/1514030#1514030

Comment: "You might want to use properties of the Hilbert symbol, maybe there is an explicit formula in your lecture notes", Samuele

Comment: Also this wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_symbol might help.

Comment: @eduard Thanks. I´ve found it in my lecture notes ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your base field is $\mathbf Q_p$,  a complete answer is naturally given by the Hilbert symbols. But let us follow a general approach, valid above any field $K$ of characteristic $\neq 2$, first concerning the *existence of a solution*, second the *determination of all the solutions*:

1) The quadratic equation $z^2 -by^2 - az^2=0$ admits a non zero solution iff $b$ is a norm in $K(\sqrt a)/K$, iff $a$ is a norm in $K(\sqrt b)/K$ (easy to check, this purely algebraic). In the case $K=\mathbf Q_p$, this existence criterion can be conveniently expressed in terms of the Hilbert symbol $(a,b)_p$, for the definition and first properties of which I refer to ***. The normic criterion above is equivalent to $(a,b)_p=1$. One must distinguish two cases :
(i) If $p$ is odd, write $a=a'p^\alpha$ and $b=b'p^\beta$, then $(a,b)_p=(-1)^{\frac {p-1}2\alpha \beta}(\frac {b'}p)^\alpha (\frac {a'}p)^\beta$, where $(\frac {.}p)$is the classical Legendre symbol.  (ii) As usual, the case $p=2$ requires special calculations :  if $u$ is a unit of $\mathbf Q_2$, let $\omega(u)$ be the class mod $2$ of $\frac {u^2-1}8$, $\epsilon (u)$ be the class mod $2$ of $\frac {u-1}2$; then $(2,u)_2=(-1)^{\omega(u)}$ if $u$ is a unit, and $(u,v)_2=(-1)^{\omega(u)\epsilon (u)}$ if $u,v$ are units. This covers all the possible cases.

2) Once the existence criterion is met, the determination of all the solutions is purely algebraic. Start from a particular solution $z_0=u_0+v_0\sqrt a$ s.t. $u_0 , v_0 \in K$ and $ N(z_0)=b$. All the solutions $z=u+v\sqrt a$ s.t. $N(z)=b$ are determined by $N(z^{-1}z_0)=1$. But the quadratic extension $K(\sqrt a)/K$ has cyclic Galois group, and in this situation, all the elements of norm $1$ are given by Hilbert's thm. 90 : $N(w)=1$ iff  $w$ is the quotient of two conjugates, i.e. $w = \frac {r-s\sqrt a}{r+s\sqrt a}=\frac{r^2+as^2}{r^2-as^2} - \frac {2rs}{r^2-as^2}\sqrt a$. By identification, one gets the explicit expression of all the solutions $z$, but I'm too lazy to write them down.

Comment: I made a bad manipulation, and posted 2 successive (almost identical) answers. I would like to delete the first one. How do I process ?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have posted your answer 2-times, because this is really a great and very interesting answer. I admire your competence. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Since your base field is $\mathbf Q_p$, a complete answer is naturally given by the Hilbert symbols, as pointed out by @eduard. But let us follow a general approach, valid above any field $K$ of characteristic $\neq 2$, first concerning the *existence of a solution*, second the *determination of all the solutions*:

1) The quadratic equation $z^2 -by^2 - az^2=0$ admits a non zero solution iff $b$ is a norm in $K(\sqrt a)/K$, iff $a$ is a norm in $K(\sqrt b)/K$ (easy to check, this purely algebraic). In the case $K=\mathbf Q_p$, this existence criterion can be conveniently expressed in terms of the Hilbert symbol $(a,b)_p$, for the definition and first properties of which I refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2973449/300700. The normic criterion above is equivalent to $(a,b)_p=1$. One must distinguish two cases :
(i) If $p$ is odd, write $a=a'p^\alpha$ and $b=b'p^\beta$, then $(a,b)_p=(-1)^{\frac {p-1}2\alpha \beta}(\frac {b'}p)^\alpha (\frac {a'}p)^\beta$, where $(\frac {.}p)$is the classical Legendre symbol.  (ii) As usual, the case $p=2$ requires special calculations :  if $u$ is a unit of $\mathbf Q_2$, let $\omega(u)$ be the class mod $2$ of $\frac {u^2-1}8$, $\epsilon (u)$ be the class mod $2$ of $\frac {u-1}2$; then $(2,u)_2=(-1)^{\omega(u)}$ if $u$ is a unit, and $(u,v)_2=(-1)^{\omega(u)\epsilon (u)}$ if $u,v$ are units. This covers all the possible cases.

2) Once the existence criterion is met, the determination of all the solutions is purely algebraic. Start from a particular solution $z_0=u_0+v_0\sqrt a$ s.t. $u_0 , v_0 \in K$ and $ N(z_0)=b$. All the solutions $z=u+v\sqrt a$ s.t. $N(z)=b$ are determined by $N(z^{-1}z_0)=1$. But the quadratic extension $K(\sqrt a)/K$ has cyclic Galois group, and in this situation, all the elements of norm $1$ are given by Hilbert's thm. 90 : $N(w)=1$ iff  $w$ is the quotient of two conjugates, i.e. $w = \frac {r-s\sqrt a}{r+s\sqrt a}=\frac{r^2+as^2}{r^2-as^2} - \frac {2rs}{r^2-as^2}\sqrt a$. By identification, one gets the explicit expression of all the solutions $z$, but I'm too lazy to write them down.